# Update custom properties in word 2010 using apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I need to update custom property using Apache Poi after setting the new value.

I have method which set a new value for custom properties:

```
  InputStream fs = new FileInputStream("D://test.docx");        
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fs));

    POIXMLProperties props = document.getProperties();
    CustomProperties cp = props.getCustomProperties();
    if (cp != null) {
        List<CTProperty> ctProperties = cp.getUnderlyingProperties()
                .getPropertyList();
        for (CTProperty ctp : ctProperties) {
            System.out.println(ctp.getName());
            if (ctp.getName().equals("Test")) {
                ctp.setLpwstr("Test");
            }

        }
    }

    document.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("D://test.docx")));
    fs.close();
```

But when i open the document   properties values is obsolete. And i have to update them manually.

There is a way to update property values automatically using Apache Poi?
Thanks!

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are you running on Windows? If so, try writing to a different named file, as Windows is rather funny about simultaneous reads and writes to a file

Comment: @Gagravarr it happens on linux ubuntu too

Comment: Can you turn it into a small junit unit test that shows the problem? If so, please report it as a [bug in the Apache POI bug database](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, but I solved calling:

```
document.enforceUpdateFields();
```

When a user will open the document a confirmation will be opened reguarding the updated of the fields.